# bootstrap 3 navbar collapse button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I did some modification in navbar but now the toggle button is not responding on click.
Below is my code. Where I am wrong ??

---

**CODE:**

```
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">ossoc</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <button id="loginbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary narbar-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>Login</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i><a href="./register.jsp">Create account</a></button>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

---

Comment: @Randy Greencorn: thanks it works for me !

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26442510/3266248

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to change in this markup

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar collapse">
```

change the

`data-target=".navbar collapse"`

to

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

Reason : The value of `data-target` is a any class name of the associated nav div. In this case it is

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">  <-- Look at here
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     .....
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sx4XE/)

Answer (score 57):

I had a similar problem.  Looked over the html several times and was sure it was correct.  Then I started playing around with the order of jquery and bootstrap javascript.

Originally I had bootstrap.min.js loading BEFORE jquery.min.js.  In this state, the menu would not expand when clicking on the menu icon.

Then I changed the order so that bootstrap.min.js came after jquery.min.js, and this solved the problem.  I don't know enough about javascript to explain why this caused the problem (or fixed it), but that is what worked for me.

Additional info:

Both scripts are located at the bottom of the page, just before the  tag.
Both scripts are hosted on CDNs, not locally hosted.

If you're pretty sure your code is correct, give this a try.

Comment: This was my issue when I had both scripts loading at the bottom of the body.

Comment: That was my issue too. I assumed that the bootstrap collapse used css only. I need to read more.

Comment: This is the solution to my issue. Thank you. However, I put both scripts at the top. It's still working.

Answer (score 21):

In `<body>` you should have two `<script>` tags:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The first one will load jQuery from the CDN, and second one will load Bootstrap's Javascript from a local directory (in this case it's a directory called `js`).

Comment: This seems not answering the question, and the details are supposed to be in the linked resource.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, not sure how it even answers the question. Please format it properly, explain your steps of solving OP's problem.

Comment: Adding jquery script worked for me . thank you
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

Comment: This actually worked for me as well.  I'm not sure why everyone is saying that this does not answer the questions, since if these two scripts are not loaded, no menu will be shown.

Comment: I was facing this issue when I was building a React with JSX app. Turns out that the Bootstrap JS wasn't loading even though path was correct. I had to get this file from CDN. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you my bootstrap js not loading . Now it fixed

Answer (score 3):

Well i had the same problem what when i added the following code within the  tag
my problem fixed :

```
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
```

I hope this can help you guys!

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me, I used jquery.min.js file that downloaded from bootstrap site
it is not working, I tried same page with other jquery.min.js file it worked fine so if you face this problem try to reference other jquery.min.js file in your page and try again

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents, had:

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

at the end of body, wasn't working, had to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` and now it's working, Bootstrap version 3.3.6. ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was due to how I build my Nav bar. I was doing it through a jQuery plugin so I can quickly build Bootstrap components through javascript.

To cut a long story short binding the data elements of the button through jQuery .data() resulted in a collapse button that didn't work, doing it via .attr() fixed the issue.

This doesn't work:

```
$this.addClass("navbar navbar-default")
  .append($("<div />").addClass("container-fluid")
    .append($("<div />").addClass("navbar-header")
      .append($("<button />").addClass("navbar-toggle collapsed")
        .attr("type","button")
        .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
        .data("target","#" + id)
        .data("toggle","collapse")
        .html("<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"))
        .append($("<a href='#' />").addClass("navbar-brand")
          .append(document.createTextNode(settings.label))))
    .append($("<div />").addClass("collapse navbar-collapse").attr("id",id)));
```

But this does (with the changes left in comments):

```
$this.addClass("navbar navbar-default")
  .append($("<div />").addClass("container-fluid")
    .append($("<div />").addClass("navbar-header")
      .append($("<button />").addClass("navbar-toggle collapsed")
        .attr("type","button")
        .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
        .attr("data-target", "#" + id) //.data("target","#" + id)
        .attr("data-toggle", "collapse") // .data("toggle","collapse")
        .html("<span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"
            + "<span class='icon-bar'></span>"))
        .append($("<a href='#' />").addClass("navbar-brand")
          .append(document.createTextNode(settings.label))))
    .append($("<div />").addClass("collapse navbar-collapse").attr("id",id)));
```

I can only assume that this is related to the way jQuery binds .data(), it doesn't write the attributes out to the elements, but just attaches them to the jQuery object. Using the .data() version resulted in HTML:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" type="button" >
```

Where as the .attr() version gives:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#6a2034fe-8922-4edd-920e-6bd0ea0b2caf">
```

It seems that Bootstrap needs the data-nnn attribute in the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

In case it might help someone, I had a similar issue after adding Bootstrap 3 to my MVC 4 project. It turned out my problem was that I was referring to bootstrap-min.js instead of bootstrap.js in my BundleConfig.cs.

Didn't work:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-min.js"));
```

Worked:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```