# Bootstrap 3.0 nav responsive toggle button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navigation, toggle

I have checked out similar answers to this question and have set up my code similar to this response here, but still cannot get it to work:

[bootstrap 3 navbar collapse button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719607/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse-button-not-working)

I even tried using the exact code for the default `navbar` on the Bootstrap 3 site, but it still doesn't work.

I've included these two links in the head section and my paths are correct:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"

My relevant code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse role"="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made a couple of small errors which is why the button doesn't work:

1) You have a typo on the `<nav>` element with a misplaced quote at `navbar-inverse role"="navigation"`

2) Your `data-target` for the button should be `#nav-collapse` since it's an id and not a class.

That's it, here's the **[working](http://www.bootply.com/Q86MrNoRvs)** version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included the latest jQuery library and Bootstrap's javascript file.